# Box-shadow issue on IE8 & IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Used below HTML & CSS for the container. No issues in modern browsers. On IE8, box-shadow not working.. so padding white background missing.

On IE11, not sure why 1px border cut off happening. Zoom level 100%.

**HTML**

```
<div class="head-row">
  <div class="head-featured">
    <h1>
      <span>Your ambitions. Our Solutions.</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.head-row{
  width: 47%;
}

.head-featured {
    background: none;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 0 18px 0 20px;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 50px;
}

.head-row .head-featured span{
    display: inline;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 2.375em;
    color: #292576;
    padding: 5px 0;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
    -moz-box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #fff, -20px 0 0 #fff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #fff, -20px 0 0 #fff;
    box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #fff, -20px 0 0 #fff;
    zoom: 1;
}
```

[image: IE8 - Box shadow not]

[image: IE11 - Border empty space only on IE11.]

Comment: Where is your IE8 specific box-shadow code? CSS `box-shadow` is not supported in IE8, obviously. Read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow).

Comment: Hi Raptor... yes i know it wont work on IE8.. but is there any filter to fix this issue or technically not possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CSS `box-shadow` is not supported by IE8, as [it needs IE9+](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow). You may simulate some similar output using `filter`:

```
.box-shadow {
   zoom: 1;
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=20, OffY=0, Color=#ffffff);
}
```

You may [read more](http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/) about `box-shadow`.

## In action

```css
.head-row{
  width: 47%;
}

.head-featured {
  background: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0 18px 0 20px;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
}

.head-row .head-featured span{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 2.375em;
  color: #292576;
  padding: 5px 0;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -moz-box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #efefef, -20px 0 0 #efefef;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #efefef, -20px 0 0 #efefef;
  box-shadow: 20px 0 0 #efefef, -20px 0 0 #efefef;
  zoom: 1;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.DropShadow(OffX=20, OffY=0, Color=#efefef);
}
```

```html
<div class="head-row">
  <div class="head-featured">
    <h1>
      <span>Your ambitions. Our Solutions.</span>
    </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

## What to do with older browsers?

I think you should not monkey with your CSS to provide similar appearance and support older browsers. Instead you have the option to apply principles of [Progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement).

Comment: Hi Trix, Thanks.. i already applied your method to fix the issue. but, it didnt worked for me.!! Yes, it wont support IE8.. is there any possible solution technically? IE11 breaking is priority than IE8.

Comment: If you need to see some result, I think you may need to move it away from all thing white. you have `background: white`, `shadow: white`, so what do expect to see?